# Filter grouped rows with at least one value under and over criterion R

Tags: r, filter, subset

Trying to figure out how many of the companies in my panel data have at least one observation before and after a cut-off date.

Say I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(year = rep(c(2010,2012,2017,
                              2010,2012,2017,
                              2008,2009,2018,
                              2017,2008,2009,
                              2017,2008,2009,
                              2005,2004,2002,
                              2003,2004,2008, 2020)),
                 company = rep(c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E",
                                 "F", "G", "G", "G", "H", "H", "I", "J", "K", "K", "K")))
```

Which looks like

```
year company
2010       A
2012       A
2017       A
2010       B
2012       B
2017       C
2008       C
2009       D
2018       D
2017       E
2008       E
2009       F
2017       G
2008       G
2009       G
2005       H
2004       H
2002       I
2003       J
2004       K
2008       K
2020       K
```

Now I want to get a sense of which companies have at least one observation before 2017 and one observation after or in 2017 (in this example that would be companies A, C, D, E, G, and K)

I tried

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(pre = case_when(year < 2017 ~ 1),
         post = case_when(year > 2017 ~ 1)) %>%
  mutate(both = pre + post) %>%
  filter(both == 2)
```

But I need some form of grouping, adding group_by(company) does not give me the desired results either. Anyone with an elegant solution to this puzzle?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `any` by group:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(company) %>% 
  filter(any(year < 2017) & any(year >= 2017)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 15 × 2
    year company
   <dbl> <chr>  
 1  2010 A      
 2  2012 A      
 3  2017 A      
 4  2017 C      
 5  2008 C      
 6  2009 D      
 7  2018 D      
 8  2017 E      
 9  2008 E      
10  2017 G      
11  2008 G      
12  2009 G      
13  2004 K      
14  2008 K      
15  2020 K
```